# Solutions in terms of Bessel functions

Tags: special-functions

I came across this question that asked to express solutions to:

$$x^2y'' + xy' + (4x^2 - v^2)y = 0,\quad 0\le x<\infty$$

in terms of Bessel functions subject to the boundary conditions y(x) is bounded in the interval

$0\le x< \infty$ and $y(0) = 5$

The general solution to the Bessel function is $AJ_v(x) + BY_v(x)$ so is that just the answer? I don't know where y(0) = 5 comes into play though...

Comment: That's how you determine your constants $A$ and $B$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general solution of the equation 
\begin{align}
x^{2} y^{''} + x y^{'} + (a^{2} x^{2} - \nu^{2})y = 0
\end{align}
is
\begin{align}
y(x) = A J_{\nu}(ax) + B Y_{\nu}(ax).
\end{align}
Now, if $y(0) << \infty$ then $Y_{\nu}(ax)$ is not a valid solution because
\begin{align}
\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} Y_{\nu}(ax) \rightarrow -\infty .
\end{align}
That is to say that given the boundary condition $y(0) = b$ then
\begin{align}
y(0) = b = A J_{\nu}(0).
\end{align}
Solving for $A$ leads to the solution, in this particular case,
\begin{align}
y(x) = b \ \frac{J_{\nu}(ax)}{J_{\nu}(0)}.
\end{align}
Notice that this solution is only valid if $\nu = 0$ since $J_{\mu}(0) = 0$ for $\mu > 0$.